# Calling JavaScript function in a .js file from Java

Tags: java, javascript, function-call

What is the best way to call a JavaScript function in a different .js file from a Java file?

Say, I have a String like so in a Java file:

```
String test = "[name1, name2, name2]";
```

What I am trying to do is the following:

1. Convert the Java String into a JavaScript array
2. Pass the JavaScript array to a JavaScript function in a different .js file.

Thanks,
Sony

Comment: JS runs on the client side, Java runs on the server's side. The server-side does not "pass" parameters to the client-side, the server-side generates the client-side. So I don't understand the issue. Can you tell us more about what you're trying to do ?

Comment: @alfasin `Java runs on the server's side` Java also could be a java applet http://java.sun.com/products/plugin/1.3/docs/jsobject.html

Comment: @Cheery you're right. But I have a feeling that Sony didn't refer to applets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use JavaScript in a Java application, you can use [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/).

If you want to call client side JavaScript form a serverside Java web application, you can use [DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/documentation/reverse-ajax/index.html)'s Reverse Ajax.

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to integrate Javascript and Java, then you can use Rhino. See the example below for a better comprehension:

**test.js**

```
function test(array){
    for(var i in array){
        out.println(array[i]);
    }
}
```

**RhinoTest.java**

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.mozilla.javascript.Context;
import org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory;
import org.mozilla.javascript.Scriptable;

public class RhinoTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Context ctx = new ContextFactory().enterContext();

        Scriptable scope = ctx.initStandardObjects();

        try {
            Object out = Context.javaToJS(System.out, scope);
            scope.put("out", scope, out);

            FileReader fr = new FileReader("test.js");
            ctx.evaluateReader(scope, fr, "<cmd>", 1, null);
            fr.close();

            String[] strArray = {"name1","name2","name3"};
            Object jsArray = Context.javaToJS(strArray, scope);
            scope.put("jsArray", scope, jsArray);

            ctx.evaluateString(scope, "test(jsArray)", "<cmd>", 1, null);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Context.exit();
    }
}
```